# Odd spacing in 'navbar-right' in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in a website that I am creating.

The form is displayed and looks ok as I am using an example but if the user is logged in and the 'You are logged in as ...' is shown the spacing seems weird.

[image]

How can I make it so that it is inline with the buttons on the other side of the navigation bar?

```
  <?php if (!logged_in()) { ?>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="user">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="pass">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="login">Sign in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="register">Register</button>
  </form>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="navbar-right">
    You are logged in as <strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?> </strong>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

I've tried adding `style="line-height:42px;"` to the element but it doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height property to `.navbar-right` class

```
.navbar-right {
    line-height:42px;
}
```